# Android filter intents by their origin

Tags: android, android-intent

is there please a way to get the origin of an `Intent`, i.e. 'who called the intent', from the receiver app? I.e. I have an app that responds to, say, `MYINTENT`, but only wants to respond to them when they come from a whitelisted app.

I've gone through the documentation on `Intents` and `IntentFilters`, but cannot find anything useful; all `getPackage()` and alike methods point to packages callable by the `Intent`, not to who raised it in the first place.

Is there really no way to track the origin of an `Intent` in Android? :-/

(I'm not the developer here, more of a security-concerned guy, and there's no room to change the design using Intents for inter-app communication. However, if possible, I'd like to secure it reasonably.)

Comment: Hey, You can check getReferrer on Activity.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getReferrer()

Comment: In short, there is nothing like this that you should be using for security purposes. If you *initiate* the communications, you can verify who you are talking to.

Comment: @bongo: thanks, but "Note that this is not a security feature -- you can not trust the referrer information, applications can spoof it." However, the originating app might sign the referrer and the receiving app then verify it, which may constitute a solution.

Comment: If you have control over all of the applications, you could build your own security mechanism like generating some security token by one app, including it in Intent, and validating it by another app.
I can even imagine some remote service that would be responsible for the generation, validation and revoke of those tokens.
But to answer your question… Indeed there is no reliable and secure solution that can be used out of the Box.

Comment: I thought so, but I wanted to confirm. It's a pity Android does not have it, this should be an OS-level feature/responsibility and not something everyone has to stitch together themselves. Anyway, thanks!